# Why does the nif function block the Erlang VM from scheduling other processes?

Tags: erlang, beam, erlang-nif

When the Erlang VM beam runs some code written in C,the other processes written in Erlang was not scheduled.
For example:

```
static ERL_NIF_TERM
        nifsleep(ErlNifEnv* env, int argc, const ERL_NIF_TERM argv[])
        {
            sleep(10);
            return enif_make_atom(env, "ok");
        }
```

when you call this C function in Erlang,the other processes was not schedulling normally.
I want to know why?
Is this a feature or is limited by the implementation(that is,this is a bug)?

The address of the code above is in:https://github.com/davisp/sleepy

Answer (score 6):

beam processes are not  mapped to OS threads directly. There is normally 1 scheduler per core.  Your call to

> sleep(10);

is blocking the scheduler that executed it (as expected,  otherwise it would have to intercept that call somehow to make it non-blocking), and so the scheduler can't execute any other erlang process until the call returns. 
Long running nif are strongly discouraged. A quick google is enough to find many references,  see for example 
http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erl_nif.html#lengthy_work

http://osdir.com/ml/erlang-questions-programming/2013-02/msg00275.html

http://ninenines.eu/articles/erlang-scalability

for comprehensive info about how the scheduler work, see
http://jlouisramblings.blogspot.com.ar/2013/01/how-erlang-does-scheduling.html